# Get DNS request from different subnet

Tags: routes, dns, firewall

I have a simple network setup, a main PC and a small DYI PiHole style device, both connected to an UISP EdgeRouter X.

Hole has address `10.0.0.1`

PC has address `10.1.1.1`

Respective gateways are `10.0.0.254/24` and `10.1.1.254/24`, respectively on ports `eth0` and `eth1` on the EdgeRouter X.

I managed to get both SSH and HTTP(S) working from PC to Hole through firewall rules. However the same rule for DNS service port 53 doesn't seem to be working at all.

My rules are as follows :

[image: rules]

I can see traffic on both SSH and HTTP(S) but nothing from the DNS (image numbers are packets and bytes) :

[image: traffic]

`drill` gives me this error : `Error: error sending query: Could not send or receive, because of network error`.

`doggo` gives me this error : `error="read udp 10.1.1.1:57260->10.0.0.1:53: i/o timeout"`

Even when disabling all rules and setting everything to ACCEPT, DNS queries still won't be answered, so I'm lost here. The server is `dnsmasq`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because, from the dns tag: DNS QUESTIONS MUST BE PROGRAMMING RELATED. Use this tag for programming questions related to writing code that interacts with the Domain Name System (DNS); for example, writing code that uses gethostbyname()

Answer (score 0):

I found what was wrong, `dnsmasq` refuses queries from different networks.

https://superuser.com/questions/1255211/dnsmasq-not-answering-dns-queries-from-routed-subnet